# How to send array from html to node.js and then to mongodb?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, mongodb

Need to send values of *long* and *lat* as one array in input, then save it in the database. Found a lot of examples that explain how to handle arrays, but most of them are in PHP.
Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function geoFindMe() {
            var coordinates = document.getElementById("coordinates");
            if (!navigator.geolocation) {
                alert("Geolocation is not supported by your browser");
                return;
            }
            function success(position) {
                var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
                var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                var coordinates = [longitude, latitude];
                document.getElementById("coordinates").value = coordinates;
            }
            function error() { alert("Unable to retrieve your location"); }
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>   
    <label for="pos">Allow location service</label>
    <input name="pos" id="coordinates" type="checkbox" onclick="geoFindMe()" value="coordinates[]">
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const newUser = new data({
        geometry: {
            type:'Point',
            coordinates: req.body.coordinates
        }
    });
});
```

**data.js**

```
const FindMyLocation = new Schema({
    geometry: {
        type: {
            type: String,
            default: 'Point'
        },
        coordinates: {
            type:[Number],
            index: '2dsphere'
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Are you using Mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Ajax to call the API to send the request.

```
<script>
        function geoFindMe() {
            var coordinates = document.getElementById("coordinates");
            if (!navigator.geolocation) {
                alert("Geolocation is not supported by your browser");
                return;
            }
            function success(position) {
                var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
                var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                var coordinates = [longitude, latitude];
                document.getElementById("coordinates").value = coordinates;
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.open("POST",URL, true);
                xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
                xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({"coordinates":coordinates}));
            }
            function error() { alert("Unable to retrieve your location"); }
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
        }
    </script>
```

in your api you will need mongoose or mongodb package for insertion

```
var data = require('data.js');
app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const newUser = new data({
        geometry: {
            type:'Point',
            coordinates: req.body.coordinates
        }
    });
newUser.save(err => {
if (err) return res.status(500).send(err);
return res.status(200).send("your success message");
});
```

In your data.js you will be needing at the end of file so that it could be acessible.

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('FindMyLocation', FindMyLocation );
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1

Comment: @mohumnali are you using JSON.parse in your code to parse any object?

Comment: No I did not use it. Where should I use it?

Comment: @mohumnali you are getting this error in API or on client?Please check the line number where you are getting, this error generally occurs when we try to parse any existing JSON object.

Comment: when i comment (xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");) the err gone but i got nothing in database

Comment: i mean like this  //xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

Comment: @mohumnali Got the error make following changes to your client script.
`xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');`
 `xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({"coordinates":coordinates}));`
The error was xhttp.send function expect a string as argument and parse it to the Content Type described for request body ,but here it was trying to parse JSON Object and hence giving error `Unexpected token o` .

Comment: (node:5780) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: FindMyLocation validation failed: geometry.coordinates: Cast to Array failed for value "44.3593993,33.2470303" at path "geometry.coordinates"

Comment: I really tried many times before i ask  
So I appreciate your help

Comment: @mohumnali have you tried to implement 
I guess promise error could be handled with these line:
`.then(function() {
    console.log('saved')
  }, function(err) {
    // want to handle errors here
  });`

Cast to Array error is coming because you are assigning string value to geometry.coordinates array,but it is defined as array in your schema. you can use `arrray.split(',')` to convert string to array.

Answer (score 0):

To send the form data, add a jQuery Ajax call in your HTML script:

```
function geoFindMe() {
    // get input's value
    var coordinates = document.getElementById("coordinates").value;
    // post coordinates to "/"
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/",
        data: coordinates,
        success: function() {
            // do things if successful
        }
    });
}
```

To get HTML form data in Express, you need to use the `body-parser` middleware. Additionally, the object property name you access the data through is based on the `name` attribute of the HTML input, not the `id`.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
    const newUser = new data({
        geometry: {
            type:'Point',
            coordinates: req.body.pos
            // property is "pos" because form input name is "pos"
        }
    });
});
```

And then to insert the data into MongoDB through Mongoose, you would do something like this:

```
newUser.save().then(() => console.log('user saved'));
```

Comment: is there some thing to require before using ajax because i got nothing in database

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `ajax` as it's been used widely on browsers for API call. This sends data from browser to server.

this is part of javaScript only so don't get confused.

Will be using inline `script` and only additional code that you need.

**On seting value of input like `<input value ="coordinates[]">` You are not setting any array as value it's just a string. Like var a = "coordinates[]"; a is not an array just a string.**

HTML and JS:

```
<body>
    <label for="pos">Allow location service</label>
    <input name="pos" id="coordinates" type="checkbox" onclick="geoFindMe()">
    <p onClick="sendCoordinatesToNode()">Click Here to Send Coordinates To NodeJs</p>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function sendCoordinatesToNode() {
        var coordinates = $('#coordinates').val();

        $.ajax({
            "url": "http://localhost:4000/", // this is url path of your API or just "/"
            "method": "POST",
            "data": {coordinates}
            // Feel free to set headers if needed, like content-type: application/json
        })
        // If API returned success then here
        .then( result => {
            // Message to notify success submition
            alert("Successfully added user.");
            return;
        })
        // If API returned error then here
        .catch ( err => {
            // Notify in case some error occurred
            alert("An error occurred.");
            return;
        });
    }
</script>
```

Now you will be able to get coordinates at `req.body.coordinates`;

Comment: I work only on SQL, so can only guide you how to send data with mongo. You need to set connection to mongo in nodeJs probably using mongo.js, better to follow these links `https://codeburst.io/hitchhikers-guide-to-back-end-development-with-examples-3f97c70e0073` , `https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs`.

Comment: (node:7568) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: FindMyLocation validation failed: geometry.coordinates: Cast to Array failed for value "44.48,33.26" at path "geometry.coordinates"

Comment: i think the cause is index  because i got this every time i run app.js==>(node:8188) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.